# Core Data Save Date Error

Tags: swift, core-data

I am trying to save a new object coming from a `json` file with `Core Data`. In this object there is a `timestamp` in `string` format. First I convert it into an `NSDate` then set it to the `timeStamp` property of the object.

I have `Posts` entity in core data model, and there are the following attributes:

**Attribute-Type**

- content-string
- title-string
- timeStamp-Date

**I get the following error:**

> Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=134100 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 134100.)" UserInfo=0x7f86cac69580 {metadata={
>       NSPersistenceFrameworkVersion = 519;
>       NSStoreModelVersionHashes =     {
>           Posts = <2c8eee3f 71ece20d 3b7daa20 e8e835ec 89126883 0b53dbd6 62992f34 dc3fb804>;
>       };
>       NSStoreModelVersionHashesVersion = 3;
>       NSStoreModelVersionIdentifiers =     (
>           ""
>       );
>       NSStoreType = SQLite;
>       NSStoreUUID = "CF57FEED-4E12-463F-8E5C-11F004518AE9";
>       "_NSAutoVacuumLevel" = 2;
>   }, reason=The model used to open the store is incompatible with the one used to create the store} with userInfo dictionary {
>       metadata =     {
>           NSPersistenceFrameworkVersion = 519;
>           NSStoreModelVersionHashes =         {
>               Posts = <2c8eee3f 71ece20d 3b7daa20 e8e835ec 89126883 0b53dbd6 62992f34 dc3fb804>;
>           };
>           NSStoreModelVersionHashesVersion = 3;
>           NSStoreModelVersionIdentifiers =         (
>               ""
>           );
>           NSStoreType = SQLite;
>           NSStoreUUID = "CF57FEED-4E12-463F-8E5C-11F004518AE9";
>           "_NSAutoVacuumLevel" = 2;
>       };
>       reason = "The model used to open the store is incompatible with the one used to create the store";
>   }

Here is my code:

```
    for item in items {
                        if let title = item["title"] as? String {
                            if let content = item["content"] as? String {
                                if let timeStamp = item["published"]! as? String {

                                    let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
                                    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss Z"
                                    let date: NSDate? = dateFormatter.dateFromString(timeStamp)!

                                    println(date!)

                                    var newPost = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("Posts", inManagedObjectContext: context) as! NSManagedObject

                                    newPost.setValue(title, forKey: "title")
                                    newPost.setValue(content, forKey: "content")
                                    newPost.setValue(date!, forKey: "timeStamp")

                                    context.save(nil)
                                }

                            }
                        }

                    }
                }
```

Comment: Is that the **complete** error message? There's almost always more than just that.

Comment: @TomHarrington I updated the error code, thanks for your response

Answer (score 0):

Try this
Go to the simulator and press reset contents and settings. This error usually happens when you chance some properties in core data.